# Array push another array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

The following is the current array return from database via eloquent of laravel. I want to push something into the array and may i know how to?

The data in the return

```
Company Object ( 
[attributes] => Array ( 
    [id] => 1 
    [company_name] => superman 
    [company_fullname] => Superman Ent. ) 
[original] => Array ( 
    [id] => 1 
    [company_name] => superman 
    [company_fullname] => Superman Ent. ) 
[relationships] => Array ( ) 
[exists] => 1 
[includes] => Array ( ) )
```

while i can call this via foreach the array and access by {{ $x->company_name }}. I want to extend the array with some custom information like, total member count?

I tried in this way and failed.

```
$temp = array("count" => "1232");
array_push($companyInfo, $temp);
```

I got this

> array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given

**Update**
The companyInfo array is return by laravel, and due to my foolish & careless (few days sleepless night +_+)  i didn't notice everything is inside ['attributes']! The data can be access by the follow after applied methods from the answer.

```
{{ $x['attributes']['company_name'] }}
{{ $x[0]['count'] }}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$CompanyInfo in your case is an object. You need to either specify a named parameter to save your $temp array info:

```
$temp = array("count" => "1232");
$companyInfo->temp = $temp;
```

Or cast the object into an array:

```
$temp = array("count" => "1232");
$companyInfo = (array) $companyInfo;
array_push($companyInfo, $temp);
```

Comment: Thx. I notice successfully pump into companyInfo. but, may i know how can i access from the view? [0] => Array ( [count] => 1232 ) the same [0] for all the data in companyInfo.

Comment: If you do $companyInfo->count = '1234'; then that data will be saved in the $companyInfo object and you will be able to access it as $companyInfo->count wherever that object is available to you.

Comment: but the count is not in the companyInfo (model object), tried and returned "Creating default object from empty value". If do like what you does? actually it could be save but just can't access

Comment: The $companyInfo object might be configured to not accept additional data (among other things). You can create an array-copy of that object ($copy = (array) $companyInfo;), then save the count into it ($copy['count'] = '1234'), then pass the $copy array to the view.

Comment: On the other hand, I suspect that you can (and probably should) push your count into the 'attributes' property. I.e. array_push($companyInfo->attributes, $data); ought to work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Try do it with out function array_push:

```
$temp = array("count" => "1232");
$temp[] = $companyInfo;
```

or

```
$temp = array("count" => "1232");
$temp['companyInfo'] = $companyInfo;
$temp['companyInfo']->getSomeData();
```

Comment: May i know if i add in reverse way, how can i access the company_name?

Comment: He needs to save $temp into $companyInfo, which is an object. Not the other way round.

Answer (score 1):

You have got array_push error because you passed an object instead of an array.

You're almost right just do following changes,

```
$companyInfo = (array)$companyInfo;

array_push($companyInfo, $temp);
```

Comment: That won't work. You're trying to pass a function result by reference. Cast before pushing.